# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_hierarchical_classification.tests' for hierarchical classification in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a hierarchical classification model using `sklearn_hierarchical_classification`.

```
from sklearn_hierarchical_classification.classifier import HierarchicalClassifier
from sklearn_hierarchical_classification.constants import ROOT
from sklearn_hierarchical_classification.metrics import h_fbeta_score, multi_labeled
from sklearn_hierarchical_classification.tests.fixtures import make_digits_dataset
```

The first 3 imports run fine, but the last command is giving me the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_hierarchical_classification.tests'
```

Notice that the above commands are taken verbatim from the library's own example script at [Github](https://github.com/globality-corp/sklearn-hierarchical-classification/blob/develop/examples/classify_digits.py).

I have tried to install the package using:

```
pip install sklearn_hierarchical_classification.tests
```

but no luck. Can anyone help me if there is anything else I should be trying?

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should try:

```
pip install sklearn-hierarchical-classification
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Rajeev Nayan Agrawal, but I have done that. I have install that package. The problem is when I try to run .tests

Answer (score 0):

this might be happening because tests is a directory that hasn't been added to PYTHONPATH ,have you tried dynamically appending the path to sys.path for example:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('realtive/path/to/directory/tests/')
from sklearn_hierarchical_classification.tests.fixtures import make_digits_dataset
```

you can also try adding the path at the beginning so its searched first , incase of name conflicts like this:

```
sys.path.insert(1,'realtive/path/to/directory/tests/')
```

Comment: can you share a little bit more about your project structure ? where are you running the code written in the question? also what's your project file hierarchy structure?

Comment: I am literally replicating what is done in the example at the moment. Then I will apply it to classify my data. Unfortunately, even the example does not seem to be working which is strange. I have done everything I could but still not able to run 'tests'. I am not applying it to my data yet as I just want to learn more about the package for now.

Comment: I am even wondering if anyone ever used this package because I hardly find any other resource talking about it.

Comment: its weird , the dir has an __init__ file and python should look at it as a package , I don't see anything wrong with the GitHub code , try this brute force solution : try using `sys.path.insert(1,abs_path)` with abs path as  `os.path.abspath('../sklearn_hierarchical_classification/tests')` then doing  `import fixtures`